# c# Windows Service new thread on event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

I have windows service which subscribes to a RabbitMQ queue when the service starts.

```
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {

            channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: _serviceConfiguration.ExchangeName, type: _serviceConfiguration.ExchangeType);
            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

            channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                                exchange: _serviceConfiguration.ExchangeName,
                                routingKey: _serviceConfiguration.RoutingName);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);


            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                //do stuff
            };

        }
```

The action that gets performed on the message can be time consuming as it calls multiple other web services.

Am I correct in assuming that I can improve performance by starting a new thread for each consumed message? Each new thread would spend most of it's time waiting on a response from an external call.

How would I go about that? I'm a bit confused about tasks/threads/await-async.

I would want to cap the number of threads created to some configurable amount as the incoming messages could be queued up far faster than they are processed.

Comment: If you want to know if it's faster then try it out, and see if it ends up being faster.  There's lots of readily available information on how to go about parallelizing operations.

Comment: Various `TaskSchedulers` offer limited parallelization, including `QueuedTaskScheduler`.  Alternatively, you can use a `SemaphoreSlim`